# How to multiply out the same lists

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list of the following form:

```
{1,1,1,0,1,1,1}
```

How can I create a list containing 5 of these lists ie:

```
{{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1,1,1}}
```

Comment: e.g. `ConstantArray[{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 5]`, `Table` would do the same thing.

Comment: Yep, was about to post that as an answer. Got me first.

Comment: Ok for example, I want to generate 5 lists of random 0s and 1s, each of length 10:

Comment: If the five are identical then `ConstantArray[RandomInteger[1, 10], 5]`; if each is random then `RandomInteger[1, {5, 10}]`

Answer (score 2):

Besides `ConstantArray` and `Table`, one can use `KroneckerProduct` as well

```
vector = {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1};
KroneckerProduct[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, vector]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Table[a, 5] /. a :> {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}

(* {{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
  1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}}  *)
```

Have fun!